# Changing the value of an enum to an inputted string from scanner? - Java

Tags: java, variables, enums, java.util.scanner

Hi im just wondering what the best way to do this is. Basically I have an enum class with three different brand names. In the program I have created, the user must have an option to select which brand they want to change, and be able to input a string to change the selected brand to.

Im not that familiar with the manipulation of enums and anything I try such as creating a variable called userInput and trying to assign the enum value to this I receive errors.

Anyone any idea? cheers

EDIT : MY METHOD BELOW:

```
public void updateBrand(Scanner input) {

        boolean valid = false;
        int selection;
        System.out.println("The list of available brands are below:");
        System.out.println("1 - " + Brand.Highstreet);
        System.out.println("2 - " + Brand.TedBaker);
        System.out.println("3 - " + Brand.FrenchConnection);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of the Brand you wish to change.");
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                selection = input.nextInt();
                if (selection < 1 || selection > 3) {
                    valid = false;
                    input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a number betwen 1 and 3");
                } else
                    valid = true;
                    System.out.println("You have selected number: " + selection);
                    if (selection == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter the changes you want to make to the brand :" + Brand.Highstreet);
                        System.out.println("New brand name : ");
                        String newBrand = input.nextLine();
                        Brand.Highstreet.????
                        //error on line above?? not sure what code to use.
                    }
            }

        } while (!valid);
    }
```

My Enum Class:

```
package SuitProg;

public enum Brand {

    Highstreet,TedBaker,FrenchConnection;

    public String st;

    void Brand(String s){
        this.st = s;
    }

    void change(String newString) {
        this.st = newString;
    }

    String getContent() {
        return this.st;
    }

}
```

Comment: If your enum class is called `Mario` and one of its 3 members is called `Luigi` you can write `Mario brand = Mario.Luigi;`. You should get no errors from this.

Comment: the code for my method in question is included in the post now. My enum class is called Brand and the 3 items are FrenchConnection, Highstreet and TedBaker. I need the method to be able to change say Highstreet to a string input from the user eg a variable created called inputtedString..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code to change the values from an enum

```
class Test
{
    enum MyEnum
    {
        BRAND_1("A brand"),
        BRAND_2("A second brand"),
        BRAND_3("A third brand");

        private String st;

        MyEnum(String s)
        {
            this.st = s;
        }

        void change(String newString)
        {
            this.st = newString;
        }

        String getContent()
        {
            return this.st;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        MyEnum c1 = MyEnum.BRAND_2;

        c1.change("A magic brand!");

        System.out.println(MyEnum.BRAND_2.getContent());
    }
}
```

Althought, enums are designed to behave as constants, so you might use another kind of structure for your purpose

Comment: so you must have methods in the enum class in order to be able to manipulate them? and what is the difference between a .getContent() and a .toString() methods? cheers

Comment: You can also declare `private String st;` as `public String st;` and manipulate it directly. There is no difference, I just didnt override it, but you can just override it to print `st`

Comment: I have posted the code for my enum class above in the post.. The application is now working but Im not really sure what some of that code is  doing specifically. What does the void method Brand do?

Comment: You have a typo in your code, you declared the constructor as `void Brand(String s){`, which is the schema of a method. Change it to `Brand(String s) {`

Comment: If i make the changes to the constructor, I get an error saying "The constructor Brand() is undefined."

Comment: Because you have to declare the constanst with an initial value like `Highstreet("Highstreet"),TedBaker("TedBaker"),FrenchConnection("FrenchConnection");`. The reason is that after you change the constructor, you have to update how the constants are created.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now. I have never declared an enum class like that before, I just declare them the way my code is at the minute. Thanks